# Difference in area calculation between QGIS and R

Tags: qgis, r, area

I used R to calculate the area of [every land polygon of the world](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons) (Projection of the source shapefile: WGS84; CRS: EPGS: 4326).

To do that, I loaded the required packages ("sp" and "raster") and I simply used this line of code:

```
polygon_name$new_field <- area(polygon_name)/1000000
```

I divided by 1000000 to obtain the area in square kilometers.

However, repeating the same operation with QGIS 3.0.3 for some random polygons, I observed that the result is slightly different. For example, with R the surface of Antarctica is 13,924,270 kmq, whereas using QGIS is 13,761,440 kmq.

What could cause such difference?

Comment: Antarctica is a bit special in a lat-long projection, being around the pole. Can you add a couple more examples, perhaps some nearer the equator?

Comment: isnt EPGS 4326 in lat lon units??

Comment: It's likely you've got an ellipsoid set for your qgis project, so you may be comparing Cartesian vs ellipsoidal areas.

Comment: @Spacedman, there is a difference between the two methods in every polygon, also for the equatorial ones.

Comment: @ndawson, actually, in the project properties (General -> Measurements) the WGS84 elipsoid is set. However, looking at the CRS of the original shapefile  I read in R before the area calculation `crs (shapefile_name)`, I obtained the following 

`+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs=0,0,0`